# File Handling C++ with xcode. simple ofstream out not working

Tags: c++, xcode, file-io

I wanted to do simple file handling test program in Xcode. But it gives me an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream out("test");
    out<<"pen"<<"\t";
    out<<"25";
}
```

Error:

> Implicit instantiation of undefined template `std::basic_ofstream<char>`

Comment: `fstream.h` is not, and has never been, a standard header. Use `fstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error means that you have to write fstream instead of fstream.h . The second error would be caused by the first one. Look at my g++'s output when I try to compile your example:

example.cpp:2:21: fatal error: fstream.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

In this link, you will find ofstream's class specification. I think it can be helpful for you:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/